# Jenkins deletes jobs on restart or reloading configuration from disk

Tags: jenkins

I've just updated to the latest version of Jenkins (1.488) for Windows 7 (64-bit), but it seems that if I restart Jenkins or select the *Reload Configuration from Disk* option, the jobs that I have configured disappear.  If I create a new job, I can see it under `JENKINS_HOME/jobs` but, for some reason, Jenkins is not able to pull these jobs back into memory.

Any ideas what I could try?

Comment: Are your permissions on the jobs folder correct? Can you make sure that the entire folder (JENKINS_HOME) is owned by the jenkins user and that it has full control?

Comment: Are the jobs really deleted, or just not shown by Jenkins in the web UI?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to permissions, as mentioned by **[Sagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289812/sagar)** above.

Make sure the user running the Jenkins (or the service running Jenkins)
is the **owner** of the `%JENKINS_HOME%` folder-tree
and that it has **full permissions** to **all** items there.